# condition statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I have a data frame that contains the below column. I want to write conditional statement like this:

```
df $ [df$literacy==FALSE,] eduyears <- 0
```

It means that if `df $ literacy is FALSE`, then in the `eduyears` column for that specific row it should set number `0`. But this command does not work on my system.

Is it correct? If it is not correct what statement should I use instead?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
df$eduyears[!df$literacy] <- 0
```

`df$literacy` is a logical vector. If you negate it (`!`), `FALSE` becomes `TRUE` (and vice versa). This vector can be used as an index for `df$eduyears`.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly then this should do:

**EDIT:(After the comment)**

```
dat$eduyears <- ifelse(dat$literacy==FALSE,0,dat$eduyears)
```

Assuming your Input looks like this:

[image]

THEN

Your ouput should be like this:

[image]

Is this what you want?

Comment: No I don't want it because I have other numbers for education year (7,8,9 ,10,...) if student= true and I just want for student=false put df$ eduyears =0. so I need a command that just work in student=false

Comment: I have attached some screenshot, you should put some input data as sample.